# why is *selecting* a primary key faster than a foreign key?

Tags: mysql

I thought I had a halfways workable understanding of databases, but that assumption just got thrown out the window.

I have a pretty large table, and I run a simple query on it:

```
select image_set_id from image where table_id = 554;
```

image_set_id is a LONG foreign key to another table. This query takes upward of 7 seconds to complete on my machine (quite a bit longer on the database server, which doesn't have as much power...)

However, if I run this query:

```
select id from image where table_id = 554;
```

it is almost a hundred times faster. The obvious difference being, id is the primary key, also a LONG.

What is surprising is that both queries compare to a foreign key in the where clause, so I expected the two to take about the same time. I mean, the DB has to filter out all the entries matching a foreign key, then read a LONG from each of them, and that's that. The nature of the value being read shouldn't matter as much as the nature of the value being compared. If I run explain on the two queries the result even looks exactly the same:

[image]

Well, obviously I'm completely wrong, so I have two questions:
a) Why is this the case?
b) Is there any way I can improve performance when selecting the foreign key, because in the end that's what I need (this is a subquery of a larger query that needs optimisation, but it consumes over 90% of its runtime)?

**Additional data:**
The structure involved here is relatively simple. There's three tables involved: One irritatingly called image_table, one called image_set and one called image.
Each image belongs to a certain image_table. An image_set is a relation, that describes images from different image_tables that belong together (they're effectively multiple versions of the same image). So an image has a foreign key to both an image_table and an image_set, while there is no connection between the image_set and the image_table.

Here's the complete structure of the tables involved:

```
explain image;
'id', 'binary(16)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''
'image_key', 'varchar(190)', 'YES', 'UNI', NULL, ''
'image_preview_key', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'image_set_id', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'table_id', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'size', 'int(11)', 'NO', '', '0', ''

SHOW INDEX FROM image;
'image', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '20201850', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'image', '0', 'UX_image_image_key', '1', 'image_key', 'A', '20201850', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
'image', '1', 'FK_image_image_set', '1', 'image_set_id', 'A', '20201850', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'image', '1', 'FK_image_image_table', '1', 'table_id', 'A', '75099', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''

explain image_set;
'id', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'time', 'datetime', 'NO', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'camera_id', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''

SHOW INDEX FROM image_set;
'image_set', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '8317139', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'image_set', '0', 'UX_image_set_time', '1', 'camera_id', 'A', '29080', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
'image_set', '0', 'UX_image_set_time', '2', 'time', 'A', '8317139', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'image_set', '1', 'IX_image_set_time', '1', 'time', 'A', '8317139', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''

explain image_table;
'id', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'name', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'legacy_name', 'varchar(100)', 'NO', 'UNI', NULL, ''
'camera_id', 'bigint(20)', 'NO', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'instruction_id', 'bigint(20)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'trashed', 'datetime', 'YES', '', NULL, ''

SHOW INDEX FROM image_table;
'image_table', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '1128', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'image_table', '0', 'legacy_name', '1', 'legacy_name', 'A', '1128', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'image_table', '1', 'FK_image_table_camera', '1', 'camera_id', 'A', '1128', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'image_table', '1', 'FK_image_table_image_table_instruction', '1', 'instruction_id', 'A', '1128', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
```

When describing the two queries in question, they look almost identical, except that one is using an index, the other is not... although an index for it would exist:

```
describe select image_set_id from image where table_id = 554;
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "image",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": [
        "FK_image_image_table"
      ],
      "key": "FK_image_image_table",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "table_id"
      ],
      "key_length": "9",
      "ref": [
        "const"
      ],
      "rows": 698122,
      "filtered": 100
    }
  }
}

describe select id from image where table_id = 554;
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "image",
      "access_type": "ref",
      "possible_keys": [
        "FK_image_image_table"
      ],
      "key": "FK_image_image_table",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "table_id"
      ],
      "key_length": "9",
      "ref": [
        "const"
      ],
      "rows": 698122,
      "filtered": 100,
      "using_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably because `id` gets encoded into each index, so it can fetch everything from the index directly.

Comment: Chances are mysql optimises the storage & retrieval of the primary key as it's so often necessary, whereas for other values it has to actually fetch and decode the data tuple. If you do have an index on `table_id` then it's even easier because in the pk case it probably has all the information it needs in the index itself.

Comment: out of curiosity, why does `describe` give a json back?

Comment: mysql workbench... there's a tabular view, but there I can only copy the values, not the keys, so posting the json seemed the clearest option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guided by Jacks suggestion to analise the queries, I noticed that the essential difference was that querying the id had "USING INDEX" in the "extra" column, and querying the image_set_id did not. That much I appended in the question.

After a bit of a wild goose chase I finally arrived at the most obvious place to look for an answer, the documentation for that particular column of the [explain output](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information), which had the following to say about the matter:

> Using index (JSON property: using_index)
>
> The column information is retrieved from the table using only information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query uses only columns that are part of a single index.

So what I had to do was create a composite Index that contained both, and *only* both image_table and image_set_id, and the query went off like a rocket with over 90% performance gain.

I had also tried an index including the image id with the two, but in that case I had to a) hint at the index to be used, and b) gained only about 30% because the query was still running through the where clause (the extra column of explain showed "using index, using where").

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this the case?

Assuming that you've got an index on `table_id`, the reason why `select id ...` is faster comes from the fact that each index also carries the primary key with it. Additionally, indices are much smaller than your main table and can often fit inside working memory.

> any way I can improve performance?

It's possible that the arity of `table_id` is very high, in which case the database may decide to just do a table scan instead; this typically points to data design flaws in your model.

That said, the first step is to always do your diagnostics first:

```
describe select image_set_id from image where table_id = 554;
describe select id from image where table_id = 554;
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. describe shows that selecting image_set_id is not using an index. But it is my understanding that foreign keys in MySql are always indexed?

Comment: Foreign keys are typically indexed, but fetching a column that happens to be a foreign key isn't the same as using the index of that foreign key.

Comment: I tried the same query explicitly stating "use index (...)", and it still has the same performance. Obviously there's something I'm not understanding at all... :(

Comment: If you were thinking of forcing `image_set_id` index, that wouldn't work; but that said, without your table structure and output of your `describe` statements, I can't do more than speculate.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with pretty much all the information I think is relevant.

Comment: is `table_id` an optional field? how many records have a `null` value?

Comment: table_id is null for images that are marked for deletion, so the amount of records can vary significantly.

Comment: Perhaps for deleted images, you may want to consider a separate table?